# jQuery File Upload delete uploaded files onbeforeunload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using [jQuery File Upload plugin by blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and everything works fine. But I've just realized that if users upload files and navigate away from the page without completing the form, it will create "orphan" files.

Is there a way to delete files onbeforeunload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, but its not guaranteed to work 100% of the time.

To make sure temp files don't pile up you have to implement some sort of 'garbage collection'. You can do it in a cron job, or with a certain probability on every upload request.

Comment: Yeah, thinking about it, with onbeforeunload, there are many scenarios where users can bypass it and the problem wouldn't really be solved. The garbage collector sounds more reliable. Thanks.